# How to detect page is refreshed in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I would like to detect when page is refreshed or reloaded in vue.js. I  have read the question from this post [Do something before reload or close in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443187/do-something-before-reload-or-close-in-vue-js). It's using window.onbeforeunload. But the problem for me, where do I put this window function ? Could we use another default method from vuejs for detecting the page that is refreshed ?
Thank you

Comment: for e.g. you could put it in root App component's `created` hook

Comment: How just persisting the data when it's created / changed into something like `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`? Why wait for some kind of "unload" hook?

Comment: @JacobGoh Would like to give an example please :-)

Comment: @Phil I have edited my question. Its supposed not related to save data

Comment: See App.vue in https://codesandbox.io/s/v6ll6mpr6l

Comment: awesome...Thank you @JacobGoh... :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the created function to call another function. Example:

```
created() {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handler)
},
methods: {
  handler: function handler(event) {
      // Do Something
  }
}

or

created() {
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
         event.returnValue = 'Write something'
      })
    },
```

Check it : https://forum.vuejs.org/t/detect-browser-close/5001/8

Comment: Don't forget to also remove the added event listener on beforeDestroy. Otherwise you might have a lot of unused event listeners slowing down your app.

Comment: beforeunload is no more supported on safari.

Comment: @KalleshwarKalshetty, where did you get that from? According to MDN, it's very well supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event.