# Is Vue's 'destroyed' method called on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am wondering if refreshing a page that runs a Vue app will trigger the Vue's [`.destroyed`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#destroyed) callback.

From what I observed in a Vue app that contains these simple lifecycle callbacks:

```
created() {
  console.log(' created');
},
destroyed() {
  console.log('destroyed')；
}
```

only `'created'` is logged (not `'destroyed'`). How can I check if the `.destroyed` callback has been executed?

Comment: FYI for others finding this in the search engines. `destroyed()` has now (Vue 3) been renamed to `unmounted()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the similar question and answer to it on stackoverflow

[Do something before reload or close in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34443187/3756237)

He/she basically explains that nothing is destroyed on page reload, you need to define

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return "Are you sure you want to close the window?";
}
```

If you want to do something before a page refresh

Answer (score 1):

As your question was

> Is Vue's 'destroyed' method called on page refresh?

**No**, `destroyed` method called if your component's controller lost or you manually destroy, above example is for manually destroy.

I have found very good example in vuejs forum which uses externally `this.$destroy()` method.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      value: 'will work until destroy'
    };
  },
  methods: {
    destroy() {
      this.$destroy();
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    console.log('Main Vue destroyed')
  }
})

var tmp = Vue.extend({
  template: `
   <div>
      <span>{{ value }}</span>
      <input v-model="value" />
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      value: 'always bind and work'
    };
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    console.log('Mounted destroyed')
  }
});

new tmp().$mount('#mount-point');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ value }}
  <input v-model="value" />
  <div id="mount-point"></div>
  <button @click="destroy()">Destroy</button>
</div>
```

[Reference](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-destroy-mounted-element-with-its-parent/3232)

Another example.  If component's control lost or removed then `destroy` method will be called of that component's

```js
Vue.component('comp1', {
  template: '<div>A custom component1!</div>',
  destroyed(){
    console.log('comp1 destroyed');
  }
})

Vue.component('comp2', {
  template: '<div>A custom component2!</div>',
  destroyed(){
    console.log('comp2 destroyed');
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      value: 1
    };
  },
  methods: {
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    console.log('Main Vue destroyed')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="value">
    <option value="1">comp1</option>
    <option value="2">comp2</option>
  </select>
  <comp1 v-if="value==1"></comp1>
   <comp2 v-if="value==2"></comp2>
  <button @click="destroy()">Destroy</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's nice but I don't think that answers the question (*is .destroy called on page refresh?*)